# I'm using VS Community edition macOS and GitHub web pages. How then can I execute a Git command?

Tags: visual-studio, github

I want to execute this command.

```
 git rm --cached .DS_Store
```

but how can I connect to Github?  I just have been using the web interface and the point and click features in Visual Studio so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Github, and, once you have logged in, click “new” repository. No need to create a README or .gitignore, so leave that unchecked.

Name your new repo.

Next, you will be shown lines you can paste into Terminal or Powershell. But wait just a second.

In the terminal, navigate to your project’s directory, and paste the lines from Github there. It’s very important to carefully ***read the instructions*** before doing so.

(Is Git actually installed on your computer? If not, you’ll have trouble.)

Once your Git repo has a remote endpoint, Visual Studio should automatically detect the endpoints, and you can push/pull as necessary.